# 16.04 Realtek RTL8723AE Wifi eventually loses connection, can't reconnect until reboot

Tags: dual-boot, lubuntu, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I don't really try to recreate the problem but it seems to occur when some form of streaming is happening. Eventually I lose my wireless connection through the Realtek RTL8723AE. It could take hours.

Enabling/disabling WiFi and/or networking and reconnecting fails. I caught a warning from `sudo service network-manager status`:

> Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate

Restarting the `network-manager` service has no affect. I typically just reboot but would like to determine the root cause of the issue. I have done some reading but have yet to come across a solution from my searches.

I also tried `sudo iplink set wlp4s0 up` and was greeted with

> RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill

`nmcli networking on; nmcli radio wifi on` has no effect... well the OS keeps trying to connect then says the connection is lost.

I've had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.0.4 and my new Lubuntu install 19.0.4 (same laptop). The WiFi adapter, a Realtek RTL8723AE, has no problem when booted from Windows.

Update containing snippet from log:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2020-02-22 03:42:53 CST, end at Fri 2020-03-20 19:34:51 CDT. --
Mar 17 11:44:26 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584463466.3201] NetworkManager (version 1.16.0) is starting... (for the first time)

## ... Too many characters for AskUbuntu

Mar 18 00:50:12 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584510612.3313] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Mar 18 00:50:12 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584510612.3317] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Mar 18 08:14:07 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584537247.9004] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   address 192.168.1.18
Mar 18 08:14:07 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584537247.9005] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 18 08:14:07 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584537247.9005] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Mar 18 08:14:07 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584537247.9005] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   lease time 86400
Mar 18 08:14:07 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584537247.9006] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Mar 18 08:14:07 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584537247.9006] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> bound
Mar 18 18:34:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584574485.2967] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   address 192.168.1.18
Mar 18 18:34:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584574485.2968] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 18 18:34:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584574485.2968] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Mar 18 18:34:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584574485.2968] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   lease time 86400
Mar 18 18:34:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584574485.2968] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Mar 18 18:34:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584574485.2968] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> bound
Mar 19 04:15:35 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584609335.1228] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   address 192.168.1.18
Mar 19 04:15:35 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584609335.1228] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 19 04:15:35 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584609335.1228] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Mar 19 04:15:35 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584609335.1228] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   lease time 86400
Mar 19 04:15:35 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584609335.1228] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Mar 19 04:15:35 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584609335.1229] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> bound
Mar 19 15:46:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584650805.4661] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   address 192.168.1.18
Mar 19 15:46:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584650805.4662] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 19 15:46:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584650805.4662] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Mar 19 15:46:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584650805.4662] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   lease time 86400
Mar 19 15:46:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584650805.4662] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Mar 19 15:46:45 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584650805.4663] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> bound
Mar 20 02:23:56 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584689036.2172] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   address 192.168.1.18
Mar 20 02:23:56 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584689036.2172] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 20 02:23:56 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584689036.2172] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Mar 20 02:23:56 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584689036.2173] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   lease time 86400
Mar 20 02:23:56 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584689036.2173] dhcp4 (wlp4s0):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Mar 20 02:23:56 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584689036.2173] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> bound
Mar 20 09:48:33 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <warn>  [1584715713.2455] sup-iface[0x564040d8d930,wlp4s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Mar 20 09:48:33 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715713.2507] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:48:33 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715713.2508] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:48:44 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715724.5730] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:48:44 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715724.5730] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <warn>  [1584715728.6475] device (wlp4s0): link timed out.
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715728.6482] device (wlp4s0): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715728.6489] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <warn>  [1584715728.6548] device (wlp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'NETGEAR11'
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715728.6566] device (wlp4s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715728.6909] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1266
Mar 20 09:48:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715728.6909] dhcp4 (wlp4s0): state changed bound -> done
Mar 20 09:49:03 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715743.5340] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:03 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715743.5341] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715744.4967] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Mar 20 09:49:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715744.4969] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1081] policy: auto-activating connection 'NETGEAR11' (23ebfc7a-1c1c-454b-b366-80a75eaa2b51)
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1094] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'NETGEAR11' (23ebfc7a-1c1c-454b-b366-80a75eaa2b51)
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1097] device (wlp4s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1104] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1111] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1116] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'NETGEAR11' has security, but secrets are required.
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1116] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1119] sup-iface[0x564040d8d930,wlp4s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1138] device (wlp4s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1147] device (wlp4s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1152] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'NETGEAR11' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1154] Config: added 'ssid' value 'NETGEAR11'
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1154] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1154] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1154] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1155] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1155] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1406] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:49:39 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715779.1407] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:49:42 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715782.6388] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:42 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715782.6388] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:43 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715783.1392] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:49:43 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715783.1392] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:49:44 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715784.2058] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:49:44 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715784.2058] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:49:47 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715787.6586] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:47 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715787.6586] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715788.6598] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:49:48 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715788.6599] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:49:49 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715789.7220] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:49:49 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715789.7221] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:49:52 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715792.6429] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:52 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715792.6430] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:49:57 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715797.6479] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:49:57 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715797.6480] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 20 09:50:01 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715801.6953] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:50:01 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715801.6953] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 20 09:50:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715804.6428] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:50:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715804.6429] device (p2p-dev-wlp4s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Mar 20 09:50:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <warn>  [1584715804.6452] device (wlp4s0): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Mar 20 09:50:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715804.6452] device (wlp4s0): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 20 09:50:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <info>  [1584715804.6458] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Mar 20 09:50:04 nolan-pc NetworkManager[834]: <warn>  [1584715804.6463] device (wlp4s0): Activation: failed for connection 'NETGEAR11'
```

To me looks like it connects properly? Then renews leases...then mysteriously fails.

I did come across something online but have not tried it yet as I'm not sure what the workings are of the options:

```
sudo modprobe -rv rtl8723ae
echo "options swenc=1 ips=0 fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723ae.conf
```

Comment: Try `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to see the log messages.

Comment: FYI, although I appreciate your noting the problem transcends just 16.04, mentioning 19.04 here may discourage some folks from responding, for 19.04 is EOL (End Of Life) and therefore not supported here. Have you considered upgrading to 19..10 which _is_ supported until the final version of 20.04 drops?

Comment: FYI: Lubuntu 16.04 LTS being a flavor of Ubuntu had only 3 years of supported life (https://lubuntu.me/xenial-5-released/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) which ended 2019-April. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server (no desktop) or Desktop (Unity 7) have 5 years of supported life and are still supported. Refer release notes, or use `ubuntu-support-status` or your own system to confirm this is the case. I suggest you move to a supported release of Lubuntu for security reasons, unless you're off-line or are aware of risks.

Comment: 16.0.4 is Ubuntu; 19.0.4  is Lubuntu. :) I hop across flavors. As for upgrading to 19.10, my experience has been after distribution upgrades I'm faced with a blank screen. Compared to prior installs I actually spent time constructing a script to tweak the system to my liking. I still have some laptops on Ubuntu 14.04. 19.04 from 16.04 was prompted by updating my XVG wallet which required a system library compile/update which failed in the middle of `make install`. I will post an update with some of the contents of the log but it is rather large at this point. Anything in particular?